# Python - Download files from Website with Google Login

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, download, google-signin

I'm trying to download files from a website using Python 3.

Direct parsing of the URL doesn't work because the URL forwards to the login page everytime, where you need to login using the Google Login button, which forwards to Google.

Is there a way to sign in and download the files using Python script? Maybe by implementing cookies in some way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium, which can automatically fill the login form for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can do that.  Follow the logic below, and change the variables to suit your specific needs.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
import time

wd = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/your_path_here/geckodriver.exe", firefox_profile=profile)
url = "https://the_url"
wd.get(url)

# set username
time.sleep(5)
username = wd.find_element_by_id("id_email")
username.send_keys("firstname.lastname@gmail.com")
#wd.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click()

# set password
#time.sleep(2)
password = wd.find_element_by_id("id_password")
password.send_keys("my_password")
elements = wd.find_elements_by_class_name("btn-primary")
for e in elements:
    e.click()

### your web scraping code goes here.
```